# Laravel no longer works after changing a config setting

Tags: laravel, fatal-error, laravel-6

I changed the timezone in the app.php file in 'Europe/Zurich' and executed the following commands with a route:

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('view:cache');
    return redirect('http://dbaziendale.test:8080/'); });
```

After that it no longer worked and this message continues to appear:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:804 Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(804): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(682): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(630): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array)
#3 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(768): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#4 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1246): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#5 C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider.php(62): in C:\laragon\www\DbAziendale\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 806
```

Laravel 6.0.1 | PHP 7.2.19

Comment: What is your laravel verison?

Comment: Did you already try `composer dump-autoload`? Also, does any value in your `.env` file contain spaces?

Comment: If this project has recently been created through composer, please make try, composer update

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It was a DomPDF problem!

In the installation it was written to insert in the file

> bootstrap/app.php

these lines:

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);

$app->configure('dompdf');
```

I took them off and started working properly again!